# Valid use of semaphore?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

I wrote this small program which uses semaphores instead of pthread_cond and pthread_mutex:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t sema;

pthread_t threads[2];

pthread_cond_t cond;

pthread_mutex_t mutex;

int value;

void * worker_a();
void * worker_b();

int main() {
    value = 3;

    sem_init(&sema, 0, 0);

    pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, worker_b, NULL);
    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, worker_a, NULL);

    pthread_join(threads[0], NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[1], NULL);

    pthread_detach(threads[0]);
    pthread_detach(threads[1]);

    sem_destroy(&sema);

    printf("Value has been set to: %d.\n", value);

    return 0;
}

/**
 * Multiplicates value by 4.
 */
void * worker_a() {
    value *= 4;

    sem_post(&sema);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/**
 * Divides value by 2.
 */
void * worker_b() {
    sem_wait(&sema);

    value /= 2;

    sem_post(&sema);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

First of all is this example correct? I mean it compiles and executes properly but maybe this is only because of the simplistic program.

As second: Do I understand it correctly that using a semaphore is just a smarter alternative to using mutex, condition variables and a lot of condition flags?

Bodo

Comment: for the second question see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)#Semaphores_vs._mutexes)

Comment: I can't be sure of the "correctness" of your solution because I don't know what you are attempting to calculate! If your goal is to create mutual exclusion, you might want to consider using [split binary semaphores (PDF warning)](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/classes/cs422/spring08/notes/4-Chapter4.pdf). In general, most systems of locks are actually implemented with semaphores.

Comment: @RyanMarcus the goal is to have value set to six as end result. This works but I am not sure if this solution is really safe

Comment: use http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for codereviews. Also Ask only 1 Question per Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct, given the goal you clarified in a comment (to have `value` end up as 6).  The ordering of execution for `worker_a` and `worker_b` is not guaranteed.

Your use of the semaphore is no different than using a plain mutex.  It merely protects `value` from concurrent manipulation, but does *not* enforce any ordering.  Throw a `sleep(5)` in to `worker_a` before it grabs the semaphore, and you'll see what I mean.

You might initialize the semaphore to *zero*, and have `worker_a` post it when it is done.  Then `worker_b` will awaken at the right time to do its job:

```
// main
// ----
   sem_init(&sema, 0, 0);  // N.B. initial value is ZERO

// worker_a
// --------
   value *= 4;             // We know a priori that sema is zero and others will wait for it
   sem_post(&sema);        // Let worker_b proceed

// worker_b
// --------
   sem_wait(&sema);        // Pause until worker_a is done
   value /= 2;
   sem_post(&sema);
```

Comment: your totally right. I have changed the order of the thread initialization and then the result is four instead of six. How could I fix this? posting the semaphore seems not to work

Comment: @bodokaiser, see updated answer for code sketch